# Reading Multiple lines in stdin using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I am trying to run a c++ program from python. My problem is that everytime i run:

```
subprocess.Popen(['sampleprog.exe'], stdin = iterate, stdout = myFile)
```

it only reads the first line in the file. Every time I enclose it with a while loop it ends up crushing because of the infinite loop. Is there any other way to read all the lines inside the `testcases.txt`?

My Sample Code below:

```
someFile = open("testcases.txt","r")
saveFile = open("store.txt", "r+")

try:
    with someFile as iterate:
        while iterate is not False:
            subprocess.Popen(['sampleprog.exe'],stdin = iterate,stdout = saveFile)

except EOFError:
    someFile.close()
    saveFile.close()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Just checking, do you want to call sampleprog.exe multiple times, bascialy once per line in the file, or do you want to call it once with all lines from the file as input?

Comment: i want to call it multiple times once per line actually, because i think calling it once with all lines from the file as input would be program dependent on what the user would pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to read all lines inside the file, assuming You want read it line by line, and pass only current line to program is

```
with open("testcases.txt","r") as someFile:
    iterate = someFile.readlines()
    for line in iterate:
        #Code
```

someFile.readlines() reads and returns the list of all lines in someFile. However, you need it to be passed to sampleprog.exe. I would use Popen.communicate() for it. Probably it's an giant overkill, but then your loop would look like

```
for line in iterate:
    s = subprocess.Popen(['sampleprog.exe'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = saveFile)
    s.communicate(line)
```

Also, You should open saveFile for writing ('w'rite or 'a'ppend options)

Comment: ahhh yes, i see it is surely a giant kill but anyways, it worked.. I haven't considered communicate as a solution because i focused on the execfile() which actually does not work because of the non ASCII character, but now i am back in the track, i would be trying to create a sandbox for this.. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You are passing to Popen a file opened for reading as stdout. I think the output should be constructed like this:

```
 saveFile = open("store.txt", "w")
```

Comment: Ok, tnx, I will look onto it